# Execute transliterated string in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, character-encoding, iconv

I want to execute a bash script from a string, say "echo TEST!" for example.
So I could go like this:

```
eval "echo TEST!"
```

Problem is, the string is transliterated in UTF-16LE to shorten the char count for golf purpose (it doesn't shorten the byte count but it's not a problem in the given context), so my actual string is "捥潨吠卅⅔".

I know how to transliterate it back, for example if I do this:

```
echo 捥潨吠卅⅔|iconv -tUCS2
```

it prints:

> echo TEST!

But when I want to execute from the string, it doesn't work.
I tried this for example:

```
eval 捥潨吠卅⅔|iconv -tUCS2
```

but it fails miserably.

Could someone help me?

Note: I usually never use Bash so sorry if the question is really dumb.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because `eval` expects a commnd or an expression to execute, instead you have to use `echo -e` in order to pipe text to `iconv`.

Comment: For same reason as explained in comment to previous answer, you cannot use `echo` or a Bash here-string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command expansion to capture the string for eval:

```
eval "$(echo 捥潨吠卅⅔|iconv -tUCS2)"
```

If you are golfing, you can further shorten it with backtics, here strings, and if the resulting command does not contain shell syntax, you can skip eval:

```
`iconv -tUCS2<<<捥潨吠卅⅔`
```

Comment: it also fail because `echo` and Bash's `<<<here-string` insert a trailing newline, which once transliterated to ucs2, adds a null byte that shell cannot execute. So you have to use `printf` instead: `printf %s '捥潨吠卅⅔'|iconv -tUCS2|sh`

Comment: @InigooMontoyaa Use single quotes to avoid `$a` expanding before `eval` is run

Comment: Ok so thanks to you the best I got so far: 1) pure bash without input -> \`iconv -tUCS2<<<CHINESE\` (17 chars) - 2) bash calling shell commands without input -> echo CHINESE|iconv -tUCS2|sh (21 chars) - 3) script with input -> eval \`echo CHINESE|iconv -tUCS2\` (25 chars). I keep the thread open in case someone suggests a shorter version.